# Sincronizacion modelo con la base de datos Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone

solicito de su ayuda para que me indiquen si es posible realizar una peticion **GET** de un solo modelo haciendole set a uno o varios atributos del modelo; me explico mejor:

Esta es una consulta que me devuelve una **Coleccion** de muchisimos modelos cuando hago `.fetch()`, pero yo lo que quiero es filtrar un solo modelo si necesidad de pedir todos los modelos y despues buscarlo

```
{
 "ciudadDepartamento": "Bogotá",
 "estadoDepartamento": true,
 "fechaCreacion": "2016-05-12T00:00:00-05:00",
 "id": 1,
 "idFacultad": {
                "ciudadFacultad": "Bogotá",
                "estadoFacultad": true,
                "fechaCreacion": "2016-05-12T00:00:00-05:00",
                "id": 2,
                "nombreFacultad": "Facultad de Ingeniería y Ciencias Básicas"
               },
 "nombreDepartamento": "Ciencias básicas"
}
```

he leigo la documentacion y dice que si quiero traer todas las **colecciones** deberia hacer `GET  /books/ .... collection.fetch();` y para los modelos `GET  /books/1 ... model.fetch();`, pero no me funciona; lo que estoy haciendo es:

```
var modelo = Backbone.Model.extend({"id": 1});
```

pero me retorna todos los modelos ejemplo:

```
modelo.toJSON(); 
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
id:1
_proto_
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienen esta misma duda lo que se debe hacer es lo siguiente:
Los modelos en Backbone tiene un atributo que define el id de un modelo con el cual va a realizar la sincronización, este atributo es `idAttribute`, este atributo se define en el constructor del modelo ejemplo

```
var modelo = Backbone.Model.extend({
             urlRoot: 'Endpoint',
             idAttribute: "id"
});
```

Después de esto le podemos hacer `set` al modelo creado y después el `fetch()` para que sincronice con el `API` así:

```
modelo.set({id:1});
modelo.fetch();
```

De esta manera este modelo se sincronizara con un objeto de la base de datos que tenga ese id.